Is the FOCAL syntax for Alphanumeric Numbers ("0XYZ") documented anywhere?
I read thru the programming manuals as well as the discussion in this question , so at least I understand what   IF(X - 0Y) ... does.  But what I can't find is any discussion of this conversion from  character to numeric operation in the FOCAL manuals (1969 and 1972) I found online.  Was it just assumed that programmers of that era knew what a PDP-X OS would do with that syntax?

The conversion is nicely explained in DEC's 1970 FOCAL Programming Manual in section 2.12, page 2-12:



The following page brings some helpful examples:



There's always a helpful manual :))

What a horrible 8141, I mean 0HACK.

Thanks -- added that manual to my collection

And today we call this "comparing strings by hash values", with a really simple hash (and actually not bothering with the strings themselves).

And with 'E' being the most commonly used letter in English, this led to a lot of overflows when trying to process "text" in FOCAL!  For example, what is the numerical value of "0OVERFLOW"?

@CrashGordon - perhaps a good reason to invent L33T speak?
